# moving entries inside of an object - why did all affected but one?

Tags: javascript

I'm busting my head over this and will appreciate help.

Have a look at this:

```js
const obj = {
    "monday": [{ "type": "close", "value": 3600 }],
    "tuesday": [
        { "type": "open", "value": 36000 },
        { "type": "close", "value": 64800 }
    ],
    "wednesday": [],
    "thursday": [
        { "type": "open", "value": 36000 },
        { "type": "close", "value": 64800 }
    ],
    "friday": [{ "type": "open", "value": 36000 }],
    "saturday": [
        { "type": "close", "value": 3600 },
        { "type": "open", "value": 32400 },
        { "type": "close", "value": 39600 },
        { "type": "open", "value": 57600 },
        { "type": "close", "value": 82800}
    ],
    "sunday": [
        { "type": "open", "value": 43200 }
    ]
}

     const keys = Object.keys(obj);
      for (let i in keys) {
        if (
          typeof obj[keys[i]][0] !== 'undefined' && 
          typeof obj[keys[i-1]] !== 'undefined' && 
          obj[keys[i]][0].type === 'close'
        ) {
           obj[keys[i-1]].push(obj[keys[i]].shift());
        }
        if (typeof obj[keys[i]][0] !== 'undefined' && obj[keys[i]][0].type === 'close') {
          obj[keys[keys.length - 1]].push(obj[keys[i]].shift());
        }
        if (typeof obj[keys[i]][0] === 'undefined' ) {
          obj[keys[i]] = 'Closed'
        }
        if (obj[keys[i]] !== 'Closed') {
          obj[keys[i]]= obj[keys[i]].map(el => {
            return new Date(el.value * 1000).toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true })
  
          });
        }
      }
            
console.log(obj)
```

if(1).find what day is starting with "type": "close" and moving it to the previous one.
if(2). taking care of cases where the first day is == 'close'.
if(3). changing the time format.

**All goes well - but:**
why friday retrieving { "type": "close", "value": 3600} and not "2 AM" ?
how can I affect that entry aswell?

Thanks

Comment: Tell us what your expected output should be.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what's *supposed* to be happening--I'd probably start by doing some light refactoring of the loop code to make things more-explanatory and less foo[bar[baz]]-y.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I tried editing the question to become clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand your algorithm, but to be honest and in terms of Third Party application maintenance, it ticks all the wrong points.
I think I've come to understand the purpose, so here's something that feels cleaner

```js
const
  obj = 
    { monday:    [{ type: 'close', value:  3600 } ]  
    , tuesday:   [{ type: 'open',  value: 36000 }
                 ,{ type: 'close', value: 64800 } ] 
    , wednesday: [] 
    , thursday:  [{ type: 'open',  value: 36000 }
                 ,{ type: 'close', value: 64800 } ] 
    , friday:    [{ type: 'open',  value: 36000 } ] 
    , saturday:  [{ type: 'close', value:  3600 }
                 ,{ type: 'open',  value: 32400 }
                 ,{ type: 'close', value: 39600 }
                 ,{ type: 'open',  value: 57600 }
                 ,{ type: 'close', value: 82800 } ] 
    , sunday:    [{ type: 'open',  value: 43200 } ] 
    }
, timeformat = { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true }
, val2date =
    val => new Date(val * 1000).toLocaleString('en-US',timeformat )
, result = 
    Object
    .keys(obj)
    .reduce((r,Day,iDay,a) =>
    {
    let hCount = obj[Day].length
    if (hCount===0 || (hCount===1 && obj[Day][0].type==='close' ))
      r[Day] = 'closed'
    else
      {
      let isLastOpen = false
        , firstHor   = (obj[Day][0].type==='close') ? 1 : 0
        ;
      r[Day] = obj[Day].slice(firstHor).map(({type,value},)=>
        {
        isLastOpen = (type === 'open')
        return val2date(value)
        })
      if (isLastOpen)
        {
        let nextDay = a[(iDay +1) % a.length]
        r[Day].push( val2date(obj[nextDay][0].value) )
        }
      }
    return r
    },{})

console.log('result = ', JSON.stringify (result,0,2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: Loving it. Thank you @Mister JoJo

Comment: if you care to elaborate why this is better than the previous one I would appreciate it!

Comment: @user2533641 There would be a lot to write about, like my code only having 2 `if`, or the isolation of the `val2date` function; you should also avoid writing meaningless things like `obj[keys[i]][0]`.